# split large XML file with node.js

Tags: xml, node.js

I've got a big 1.8gb XML file with all of its contents on one line.
The main structure of the file is this:

```
<xml>
    <mutateieoverzicht>
        <mutatiebericht> ... </mutatiebericht>
        <mutatiebericht> ... </mutatiebericht>
        ...
    </mutatieoverzicht>
</xml>
```

But then on one line :)

I want to parse the file and do some actions on the `mutatiebericht` elements (storing in db). Because loading and parsing the whole document at once takes to much memory and is terribly slow, I was thinking of parsing the file line-by-line.
But the original file has only one line.

So my first step would be to traverse the file and create a new file with every `mutatiebericht` on its own line.

I can load the file in node.js and do things with the content, but am lost regarding the splitting of the string with contents.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [xml-stream](https://github.com/assistunion/xml-stream) module, it reads a XML file into a stream and emit events on each elements start and end. It would look something like this (untested):

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(pathtoyourfile);
var xml = new XmlStream(stream);
xml.on('endElement: mutatiebericht', function(item) {
  console.log(item); //item contains your element
});
```

Comment: Does streaming mean it doesn't load the complete file in memory?

Comment: I just tried to use it, but it generates half way the file a load of 5 and it starts to use lots of swap memory. So it appears xml-stream generates a lot of memory-requests.....

Comment: If I watch the mem-usage in htop it steadily increases to finally consume the whole 1gb of memory and starts to swap....]

Comment: If anyone needs to read XML on windows and is trying to avoid `GYP`, then here's my attempt at using `sax` to create a very simple parser called `no-gyp-xml-parser` on NPM, hope it can benefit someone: https://www.npmjs.com/package/no-gyp-xml-stream